# Connecting to Amazon EC2 Instance Hangs Suddenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

So I create an Amazon EC2 instance and it works great for about a day, but then suddenly (even without any changes that I can think of) it stops being able to connect.

Here's my verbose SSH output

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/FreeJeff.pem ec2user@ec2-52-25-248-179.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-25-248-179.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.25.248.179] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/peter/.ssh/FreeJeff.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/peter/.ssh/FreeJeff.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
```

Hangs here for about five minutes... Then...

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

**Things I have done:** restarting the instance (doesn't solve the problem), terminating and creating a new instance from AMI (solves the problem only for another day), and trying different WiFi networks (doesn't work anywhere!).

`telnet ec2-52-25-248-179.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 22` does work.

**Details about me:** Connecting from OSX.

Comment: Are you stopping and restarting the instance at all?

Comment: I've done both (reboot, plus stop and start).

Comment: If you are starting and stopping the instance in classic, you will get a different IP on each boot.

Comment: Yes, I've been keeping track of the changes in IP address.

Comment: Are you connecting from a network which may have filtering on port 22?

Comment: Good question. I think port 22 works because `telnet ec2-52-25-248-179.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 22` does succeed for me.

Comment: to clarify: after 1 day you are no longer able to connect? or you're connected for 1 day and after that the connection hangs?

Comment: @Mircea: Actually, some computers and networks experience a "connection refused" and others experience a hang followed by "Connection reset by peer".

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue. something between you and the target machine is not allowing the connection through. the 1 day limit seems interesting. did you try to traceroute and/or tcp ping to the instance to see if you can get extra info?

Comment: Also, try launching another EC2 instance and (from that new instance) try connecting to the failed instance. That will eliminate any potential firewall/network problems.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I had configured the EC2 incorrectly to begin with.  Creating a new EC2 solved the problem.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly was done incorrectly?